# Unable to open the pdf in Android

Tags: android

I am new in android and working on one android project in which I have to display a chosen pdf from the device either from internal storage(Priority) or from external Storage. I am enclosing the used code below.

```
private void openLocalPDF(File pdffile) {

       File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), pdffile.getName());
        Uri path = PdfFileProvider.getUriForFile(activity.getApplicationContext(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
        Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        target.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
        Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
        try {
                activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install some pdf viewer app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Vijay Kumar Cannot Display a Pdf pdfname

Comment: What you want? I think you are trying get all pdf file list? Am I right?

Comment: What is path of your PDF?

Comment: I have chosen a one pdf from the device after choosing it I am loading it on-screen so after clicking that icon I need to display a chosen pdf

Comment: Can you add a sample of your `path` or `file.getAbsolutePath()`?

Comment: @Vijay Kumar I am simply choosing it from mobile internal storage

Comment: Use my answer this will work

Comment: using `targetSdkVersion 29` add this permission  `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

Answer (score 2):

You should create a `Provider Class` and `extends` with `FileProvider`. and register in `manifest` and also if you using `targetSdkVersion 29` add this permission `AndroidManifest.xml` `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

```
<provider
        android:authorities="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true"
        android:name=".provider.GenericFileProvider">

        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

    </provider>
```

And add a `provider_paths.xml` file in `xml` folder :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

And use this method

```
public static void openFile(Context context, File file) {
    Uri path = GenericFileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf);
    try {
        context.startActivity(intent);
    } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {

    }
}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: What is error? Can you share the log? and your code?

Comment: E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory).

Comment: This Exception has comming

Comment: Please check your file absolute path, I think the file path is invalid.

Comment: /storage/emulated/0/filename.pdf   This is my absolute file path

Comment: Can you share the exception ?

Comment: E/DisplayData: openFd: java.io.FileNotFoundException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-02-05 11:25:32.601 17574-18137/? E/PdfLoader: Can't load file (doesn't open)  Display Data [PDF : 31_202002040731165981.pdf] +ContentOpenable, uri: content://applicantId.provider/external_files/31_202002040731165981.pdf

Comment: Please use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` instead of `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Comment: I have one more change from your code snippet of Android manisfest is android:authorities="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" is replace with android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" because I am not using  androidx

Comment: Ok don't worry, have replaced  from `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` to `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()`

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

**Step - 1:** Create `provider_paths.xml` in your `xml` directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

**Step - 2:** Add `FileProvider` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
</provider>
```

**Step - 3:** Since your file is in internal/external storage use `getExternalStorageDirectory()`

```
File file =  new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), filename);

Uri path = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);

Intent target = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
target.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
target.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
target.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
Intent intent = Intent.createChooser(target, "Open File");
try {
    startActivity(intent);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Please install some pdf viewer app", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207175/discussion-on-answer-by-md-asaduzzaman-unable-to-open-the-pdf-in-android).