# Android SecurityException when trying to upload a document - JAVA

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, file-access

i am using this code to present the user with a document selection intent:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                        },
                        1);
            }
        }
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        intent.setType("file/*");
        String[] mimetypes = {"application/msword", "application/pdf", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document"};
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

but this is giving me an exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=66770, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/834 flg=0x43 }} to activity {com.mypackage/com.mypackage.activities.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/834 from pid=22086, uid=10311 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()

Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/all_downloads/834 from pid=22086, uid=10311 requires android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS, or grantUriPermission()
```

i tried changing this line

```
requestPermissions(new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},1);
```

to

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),new String[]{android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,"android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS"},1;
```

and heres my `onActivityResult`

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

            case REQUEST_CODE:
                Uri uri = null;
                File imageFile = getTempFile(getContext());
                boolean isCamera = (data == null ||
                        data.getData() == null  ||
                        data.getData().toString().contains(imageFile.toString()));
                if (isCamera) {     /** CAMERA **/
                    uri = Uri.fromFile(imageFile);
                } else {            /** ALBUM **/
                    uri = data.getData();
                }
                //Uri uri = data.getData();
                Log.e("Uri-", "" + uri);
                int hasWriteStoragePermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getContext(), "android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS");
                final int REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS = 123;
                String strPath = "";
                if (hasWriteStoragePermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) getContext(), new String[] {"android.permission.ACCESS_ALL_DOWNLOADS",
                                    android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                            REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                    strPath = CommonUtils.getRealPathFromURI(getContext(), uri);
                }

                if (strPath != null) {
                    Log.e("strPath", "" + strPath);
                    if (strPath.endsWith("pdf") || strPath.endsWith("doc") || strPath.endsWith("docx")) {
                        File file = new File(strPath);
                        // tvResumeName.setText(file.getName());
                        Log.e("file", file + "");
                        Log.e("File file", file.getAbsolutePath() + "  " + file.getName());
                        if (CommonUtils.isInternetConnection((Activity) getContext())) {
                            uploadDocuments(file);
                        } else {
                            CommonDialog.With(getActivity()).Show(getString(R.string.internet_err));
                        }
                    } else {
                        CommonDialog.With(getActivity()).Show(getString(R.string.file_err));
                    }
                } else {
                    CommonDialog.With(getActivity()).Show(getString(R.string.file_phn_err));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

i am getting the error when trying to run this code:

```
getDataColumn(context, contentUri , null, null)
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47361213/securityexception-permission-denial-access-all-downloads) question but the exception still persists i have also viewed other related questions but with no luck.

Comment: `but this is giving me an exception:` Impossible. You start an intent and the user has not even selected anything. So impossible. Please tell which statement causes the exception.

Comment: And you do not need any permission if you use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: You did not tell what you want to do with the uri/file once the user has selected one.

Comment: Please remove all code for case SELECT_ADDRESS_FROM_MAP_REQUEST_CODE: as it has nothing to do with your problem and is only confusing for us.

Comment: `strPath = CommonUtils.getRealPathFromURI(getContext(), uri);` DOnt try to get a 'real path' from uri. You can use the uri as is. Tell what you want.

Comment: `boolean isCamera = (data == null ||` What is this messing with camera? Again: you did noty tell what you are up to.

Comment: yes sorry for the confusion, the user can also use the camera to upload a picture,  select from gallery and select a file from device and upload it. which all of these are getting handled on the `onActivityResult` thats why there are some code that doesn't relate to the error at all.

Comment: Dont bother us with that. Post only code for ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: the error occurs as soon as the user selects a file from the selector and on the error log theres an error pointing to this line `strPath = CommonUtils.getRealPathFromURI(getContext(), uri);`  i will edit to include contents of this function right now

Comment: i am trying to upload the image to a database

Comment: is there a reason its working on older versions of android?

Comment: @blackapps ok how about now?

Comment: Another observation i made is the exception only occurs when i try to select the file from the Recent Files if i open internal storage and select a file everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

You should create a `Provider` Class and `extends` with `FileProvider` and register in `manifest` and allow `android:grantUriPermissions="true"`

```
<provider
    android:authorities="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true"
    android:name=".provider.GenericFileProvider">

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>

</provider>
```

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60051454/9993404) answer, I hope this will help you

Comment: i already have this code                                                                                          `<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>`

Comment: add `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);` in your `intent`

Comment: still getting the same error, i am on a deadline and i really need help. tell me if i should provide additional info.

Comment: Can you share your full stack trace and what is your `targetSdkVersion`?

Comment: Please also share your code on `onActivityResult()`

Comment: ok i will share that, i just tested on an older version of Android(Marshmellow) and works fine. i am currently getting the error on Android 9.

Comment: i have edited my question to include `onActivityResult`

Comment: targetSdkVersion is 28